# rabbitmq constantly alert Node seems down in Prometheus

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus

I setup rabbit-mq cluster version 3.8.2 .
I enabled Prometheus module in all rabbit to scrape data out of it for monitoring.
my alert system constantly shows that the rabbit is down but its not.
anyone can help me with that.

problem to scrape rabbitmq on rabbitmq1:15692 for more than 10 minutes. Node seems down.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked port 15692 in the RabbitMQ node? It will probably show you that the connection is refused.
I would recommend monitoring port 5672 to make sure your node is up. But you can also have problems with RabbitMQ, given that the prometheus plugin does not work correctly and the port is not always answered.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).